# Create OnBoarding process with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is there any way of creating OnBoarding slider on Android using MvvmCross?
I am using Xamarin with MvvmCross and I would like to create OnBoarding using this framework.

I found  a tutorial but it uses Xamarin.Forms and I cannot find some of the controls on Xamarin.Android.

Comment: What controls are you missing?

Comment: I was trying to follow this tutorial on Xamarin.Android but some of the controls I cannot find: https://medium.com/@jgentilicio/making-an-onboarding-to-introduce-first-time-users-with-xamarin-forms-94f9515612f1

Comment: which are the controls that you cannot find?
you can check https://github.com/martijn00/InfiniteCycleViewPagerXamarin
or https://github.com/mohibsheth/CarouselView for the Carousel if that's what you cannot find